# CSS - How do I make background picture always take full width even after making the format of the site smaller?

Tags: html, css

Basically I wanna make so that whenever the website gets smaller, the background should still take full width, i tried it with multiple stuff but it did not work and i am wondering how to do this, since i am making my website responsive atm. So yeah i wanna make my website responsvie and whenever i try to make the site smaller it opens at the right side and bodys background color is basically being shown and that is not what i want, i want the picture still to take full width, this happens AFTER 1595px of width.

html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chakra+Petch:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i|Orbitron:400,500,700,900&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/img/apexicon.jpg">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <title>Apax</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav  class="navigation">
        <ul class="navigation-list">
            <li class="navigation-item"><a href="#home" class="navigation-link">Home</a></li>
            <li class="navigation-item"><a href="#legends" class="navigation-link">Legends</a></li>
            <li class="navigation-item"><a href="#pros" class="navigation-link">Pros</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <header id="home" class="header">
        <h1 class="heading-title">apex legends</h1>
        <p class="heading-text">Fun. Easy. Joy.</p>
    </header>
    <section class="legends" id="legends">
        <h1 class="legends-title">Legends</h1>
        <div class="cards">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="/img/octane.jpg" alt="octane" class="card-picture">
                <h1 class="card-title">Octane</h1>
                <p class="card-text">One day, Octavio Silva was bored. In fact, he was bored most days. Heir to the
                    preoccupied CEOs of Silva Pharmaceuticals and wanting for nothing in life, he entertained himself by
                    performing death-defying stunts and posting holovids of them for his fans to gawk over. So, this
                    day, he decided to set the course record for a nearby Gauntlet by launching himself across the
                    finish line – using a grenade.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img src="/img/wattson.jpg" alt="wattson" class="card-picture">
                <h1 class="card-title">Wattson</h1>
                <p class="card-text">Natalie Paquette is a familiar face in the Apex Games, though for a different reason than most. Daughter of the Games’ lead electrical engineer Luc Paquette, she studied his manuals to stay close to him, and discovered her calling at a young age. Though she could be completely distracted one moment and hyper-focused the next, electricity grounded her – its ordered, predictable flow made sense in a way the rest of the world didn’t.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="pros">
        <h1 class="pros-title">Pros</h1>
        <div id="pros" class="cards">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="/img/mendo.jpg" alt="octane" class="card-picture">
                    <h1 class="card-title">Mendu</h1>
                    <p class="card-text">Lucas “Mendokusaii” Håkansson is a full-time Twitch streamer. He is currently focusing on the battle royale genre including Apex Legends. Mendokusaii is currently the world record holder for most eliminations in a single game.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="/img/shroud.jpg" alt="shroud" class="card-picture">
                    <h1 class="card-title">Shroud</h1>
                    <p class="card-text">Michael Grzesiek (born: June 2, 1994 [age 25]), better known online as Shroud, is a Canadian YouTuber, Twitch Streamer, and a professional eSports player and video game streamer. He is known for playing PUBG, Call of Duty: Black Ops 4 and Apex Legends. Shroud currently has 3.1 million subscribers and 280 million views on his YouTube channel along with 4.8 million Twitch followers and 235 million Twitch views, and is top 5 most followed streamers on Twitch</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>

    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```css
/* general styling */
* {
    outline: none;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Chakra Petch', sans-serif;
    background-color: black;
}

/* navigation */

.navigation {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
}

.navigation-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    list-style: none;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex: 1 1 1;
}

.navigation-link {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    color: rgb(105, 200, 200);
    text-shadow: .1rem -.05rem .8rem rgb(9, 9, 41);
    letter-spacing: .3rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: all .4s;
}

.navigation-link:hover {
    padding: .5rem;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, aqua, blue, black);
    border-radius: 3rem;
    box-shadow: .05rem .4rem .3rem rgb(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 2) scale(1.5, 1.5);
}

.navigation-link:active {
    box-shadow: 0;
    padding: .3rem;
}

/* header */

.header {
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(74, 173, 173, 0.561), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.712), rgba(136, 32, 32, 0.589), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.712), rgba(14, 14, 116, 0.561)), url(/img/apexbackground.jpg);
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
}

.heading-title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    font-size: 10rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Orbitron", sans-serif;
    text-shadow: .1rem .3rem 1rem rgb(24, 14, 114);
    color: rgb(26, 136, 99);
    left: 27%;
    letter-spacing: .3rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.heading-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 43%;
    font-size: 5rem;
    color: rgb(17, 131, 116);
    text-shadow: .1rem .1rem .5rem rgb(38, 174, 207);
    letter-spacing: .2rem;
}

/* legends */

.legends {
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.692), rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.685), rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.575), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.815)), url(/img/apexlegendsbackground.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}

.legends-title {
    position: absolute;
    left: 48%;
    top: 105%;
    letter-spacing: .3rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-shadow: .1rem .1rem .5rem black;
    color: darkblue;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.596), rgba(173, 216, 230, 0.616), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.63), rgba(0, 0, 139, 0.609), rgb(0, 0, 0));
    padding: .5rem;
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
}

/* cards */

.cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex: 1 1 1;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.card {
    height: 48rem;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 30rem;
    width: 50rem;
    box-shadow: .1rem .7rem .5rem black;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.719);
    transition: all .5s;
}

.card-picture {
    width: 25rem;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    box-shadow: .05rem .8rem .5rem black;
    left: 25%;
    background-size: cover;
}

.card-title {
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-shadow: .1rem .5rem 1rem white;
    left: 40%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Orbitron", sans-serif;
    position: relative;
}

.card-text {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-shadow: .1rem .3rem 1rem rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0 .4rem;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    letter-spacing: .3rem;
    text-align-last: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Orbitron", sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.card:hover {
    box-shadow: .05rem -.02rem 2rem black;
    transform: translate(.4rem, -2rem) scale(1, 1);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(218, 178, 104, 0.596), rgba(172, 107, 4, 0.575),
            rgba(77, 11, 5, 0.705))
}

/* pros */

.pros {
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.93), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.216), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.637), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.63)), url(/img/prosbackground.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}

.pros-title {
    position: absolute;
    left: 48%;
    top: 205%;
    letter-spacing: .3rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-shadow: .1rem .1rem .5rem black;
    color: darkblue;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.596), rgba(173, 216, 230, 0.616), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.63), rgba(0, 0, 139, 0.609), rgb(0, 0, 0));
    padding: .5rem;
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
}

/* responsiveness */

@media (max-width: 1595px) {
    .header, .pros, .legends {
        background-size: cover;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

[image: Look at the left, body background color is displaying cause picture not taking full width please help]

Answer (score -1):

I didn't find anywhere in your code where you want to put background but if it's CSS try to use `background-size: cover;`